# Load Data in RecyclerView with Firebase android

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm working with Firebase and RecyclerView inside a Fragment in Android, I request my information of FireBase with this method (1), and I get all the information very well but when I load inside the RV in the Fragment (2), the information does not display immediately, I mean I have to unclick the EditView of the View and before of that the information appears in the RecyclerView.

[image]

With this method, I get the information of Firebase(1)

```
final ArrayList<Places_Model> places_list =new ArrayList<Places_Model>();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("favoritos");
        databaseReferencePlace = firebaseDatabase.getReference("places");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String user_id = ds.child("id_user").getValue().toString();
                        if(user_id.contains(user_actual)){
                            final String id_place = ds.child("title").getValue().toString();
                            databaseReferencePlace.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                        String city = ds.child("id").getValue().toString();
                                        Log.e("IDCity",city);
                                        Log.e("IDPlace",id_place);
                                        if (city.equals(id_place)){
                                            Places_Model pl = ds.getValue(Places_Model.class);
                                            places_list.add(pl);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This is my Adapter

```
public class MyAdapterPlace extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterPlace.ViewHolder> {
private List<Places_Model> places;
private int layout;
private OnItemClickLister lister;
private Context context;

public MyAdapterPlace(List<Places_Model> places, int layout, OnItemClickLister lister) {
    this.places = places;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.lister = lister;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout,parent,false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(places.get(position),lister);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return places.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewCountry;
    public ImageView imageViewCountry;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        textViewCountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        imageViewCountry = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPoster);
    }

    public void bind(final Places_Model place,final OnItemClickLister lister){
        textViewCountry.setText(place.getCountry());
        Picasso.with(context).load(place.getPoster()).fit().into(imageViewCountry);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lister.onItemClick(place,getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

}


public interface OnItemClickLister {
    void onItemClick(Places_Model place,int position);
}
```

}

And in the `Fragment`, I inflate the RV with this code(2)

```
     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saved,container,false);
    v.setTag(TAG);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user_actual = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    placesFav = this.getAllFavs();

    //Inflando el Reycler View de Favoritos
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_favoritos);
    mlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    Log.e("PlaceFav", Integer.toString(placesFav.size()));
    mAdapter = new MyAdapterListPlace(R.layout.recycler_view_item_list_destiny, placesFav, new MyAdapterListPlace.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Places_Model place, int position) {

        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return v;
```

BTW Thanks for help me...

Answer (score 0):

example of recyclerview_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLoad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_3"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:scaleType="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHitam"
            android:text="JSon Image Name\nasasasas"
            android:id="@+id/txtJudulPromo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="JSon Image Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/txtHargaProduk"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtHargaLama"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
            android:text="JSon Image Name"
            android:id="@+id/txtHargaLama"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtHargaBaru"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="JSon Image Name"
            android:id="@+id/txtHargaBaru"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llToko"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/llToko">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_toko_3"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
                    android:text="JSon Image Name"
                    android:id="@+id/txtNamaToko"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lokasi"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_lokasi_2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
                    android:text="Bandar Lampung"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/txtLokasi"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/jarak"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_on"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
                    android:text="300 Meter"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/txtJarak"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

example of recyclerview_items_toko.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLoad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_3"
            android:background="@drawable/garis_3"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:scaleType="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/garis_3"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHitam"
            android:text="JSon Image Name\"
            android:id="@+id/txtNamaToko"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:lines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHitam"
            android:text="JSon Image Name\"
            android:id="@+id/txtNamaTokoSearch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:lines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
            android:text="JSon Image Name\n\n"
            android:id="@+id/txtAlamat"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtNamaToko"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llBtn"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/llToko">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lokasi"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_lokasi_2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
                    android:text="Bandar Lampung"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/txtLokasi"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/jarak"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_on"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSc2"
                    android:text="300 Meter"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/txtJarak"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@id/llBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btKatalog"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="Lihat Promo"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_display_images.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ecf1f4">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/tbUrut">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0 Promo"
                        android:textColor="#858585"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/tvJumlahPromo"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spUrut"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:pointerIcon="arrow"
                        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                        android:entries="@array/urut" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pb"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPB"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ll_not_found"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_info_not_found"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Maaf, promo tidak ditemukan." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tbUrut"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbUp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:onClick="ScrollAtas"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_upward"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_display_toko.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ecf1f4">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/tbUrut">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0 Toko"
                        android:textColor="#858585"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/tvJumlahPromo"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pb"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPB"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ll_not_found"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_info_not_found"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Maaf, toko tidak ditemukan." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tbUrut"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbUp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:onClick="ScrollAtas"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_upward"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```